# Error displaying results from an in_array()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried comparing values in two arrays using `in_array()`. `$friends[]` contains all ids of my friends in the friends table while `$membersarray[]` contains ids of people in a team.

What I'm trying to do here using `in_array()` is that I want only friends ids who are not part of the team to show up and it worked. But now, I want the result (`$t`) to display the surnames stored in the friends table instead of just the ids.

For example, it shows: 3, 5 and 7. I want it to show, 'john', 'doe' and 'rick'. How do I do this?

```
$friends[] = $record5['id']; //contains of ids of all friends

$membersarray[] = $output['id']; //contains ids of all team members

foreach ($friends AS $t) {

   if (in_array($t, $membersarray)) {
   //donothing                         
   } else {
     echo $t;

     }
  }
```

Comment: What variable are the names stored in?

Comment: `john` and `rick` are first names, you said you want to display surnames.

Comment: Could you do a var_dump on `$record5['id']` and post the result as an edit to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax with empty brackets after the variable name:

```
$friends[] = $record5['id']; //adds one element to the array $friends
```

to add a single element to an array.

As long as `$record5['id']` is already an array, you just need this:

```
$friends = $record5['id']; //contains ids of all friends

$membersarray = $output['id']; //contains ids of all team members
```

Comment: I don't understand. I want to display just the surnane and not the ids. The present output ($t) displays the ids.

Comment: Ahhhhh.... gotcha.  So you need to SELECT those names either in another SQL query, or better, as part of the original query. It's best to keep the number of database queries to an absolute minimum. Can you post the query you are using?

Comment: It is selected in the original query. The problem is that am storing only ids in the arrays so '$t' only displays ids because that is what is stored in it. Is it possible to get a query to select surnames from the friends table using '$t' as the ids.

Comment: Yes, you could use another query. But if it's already selected in the original query, then it's very easy to get at that data. What is your original query?